# constantly update variable in background while program is running

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, background

Im making a software to handle customers and services of a computer repair workshop using tkinter and sqlite databases. I want my program to be able to show status messages (e.g: "A cutomer debt has turn 30 days old") in some tkinter labels and I want this messages to be constantly updated  without user intervention and without them having to close and re-open the software.
I know how to get the messages and do the UI for them. But I dont even know where to start with **running background tasks in a python script**. I dont know any libraries for doing so and I have researched the topic before asking this but I coudnt find anything good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some code for what you've tried? Also, do you want the program to constantly run in the foreground?

Comment: You can either use `threading` module to create background task or `tkinter` `after()` function to perform update periodically.